# Unable to Access Network Drive as SYSTEM account on Windows 10(Windows Server 2016)

Tags: windows-10, batch, network-shares, samba

I have a scheduled task(batch script) for syncing data from a network driver everyday. The task is run as `nt authority\system` account. It works fine on `Windows 7/2008/2012`, but does not on Windows `10/2016` because the script is unable to access the network driver.

I did a test with PsExec. I'm pretty sure this issue exists only on Windows 10/2016.

Is there any configuration that I can change to fix this?

[image]

Comment: The local system account would need permission to access the file share. 
In a domain environment, this can be done by granting access to the file share to the domain account for the computer where this script is running.  If you are not in a domain environment, you would not be able to use the local system account, and would have to run the script using a user account which exists on both machines and has been granted access to the file share.

Comment: @DawnBenton Thanks for your reply! The server is not in a domain environment. If I use a user account, I have to worry about the password, which is force to expire in 3 month according to our security policy. So this kind of behavior is introduced since `Windows 10/2016`?

Comment: @Momo Wait, your security policy force to change password every 3 months but allowing passwordless access via SYSTEM account ??? It kinda strange "security" policy...

Comment: @Alex Creating a scheduled task run as SYSTEM account is not a security concern I think.

Comment: @Momo You trying to access remote system that has password enforcement policy. You need to be authorized on remote system to be able to access remote file system, but you trying to login/access there(remote system) as SYSTEM account, without password which is means NO ANY SECURITY on remote side if it really allow network connection to authorize itself as SYSTEM account. If you running a task under specified user account then all actions will be done as specified user.

Comment: @Alex

1. I have to clarify that the remote network driver I try to access is a samba server which is configured deliberately to allow anyone to read. It's a public share.

2. Network access is allowed for SYSTEM account at least on Windows Server 2008/2012, which I've tried. You can't authorize yourself as SYSTEM account itself when you try to access remote network driver. You have to provide a user account and password if the share is not public. If it's a security hole like you said, Microsoft should have fixed it years ago.

Comment: @Momo "You can't authorize yourself as SYSTEM account itself when you try to access remote network driver." - that is exactly what I meant :) because SYSTEM account is passwordless. I hope you understanding now that it hard to be a telepathic without knowing the fact that "samba server which is configured deliberately to allow anyone to read" when you wrote: "I have to worry about the password, which is force to expire in 3 month according to our security policy."

Comment: @Momo  Ok, let get back on subject, I just tested  the same situation as you are(after your clarification ;) ): remote server running samba on linux, samba config allow everyone as "map to guest = bad user", scheduled task on windows running as system user with checkbox "Run with highest privileges" ticked, I put "copy \\ip.ip.ip.ip\share\file.txt c:\Users\Public\Documents\" to test.cmd file and used it as action in scheduler. Result as expected: file copied from remote server by running task as system user without problem

Comment: @Alex Sorry I didn't describe the situation precisely. Do you mean you get this expected result on Windows 10/2016 without any special configuration? ( ･᷄ὢ･᷅ )

Comment: @Momo Yes, it works. The only may be a case - w10 computer I tried isolated from MS updates since may or  june, in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

May be this workaround will suit you:
assign a letter for your network share **with credentials**; do your job; delete letter.
 
E.g.:
 1. net use V: \\server\share /user:name1 passw2
 2. copy file.txt V:\ 
 3. net use V: /delete
(I guess you know what to put in place of name1 ant passw2)

If for some reason you have to put everything in one command line, separate commands with & or &&, e.g.:
net use V: \\server\share /user:name1 passw2 & copy file.txt V:\ & net use V: /delete

P.S. However, it seems single line command (commands separated with &) does not work in Windows7 :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have authentication information to access the target server,
Here is how to Remote access with SYSTEM account task.(does not use network drive )

1. Create a bat script to register remote server credentials in the credential manager.
   ex.　[cmdkey / add: target name / user: user name / pass: password]
2. Register the above bat file to be executed by the SYSTEM account user in Task Scheduler.
3. Perform the above tasks.
   Remote folder access is now possible with the SYSTEM account.